# Show array elements in textView (Swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, timer

How can I add all the elements from an array to a textView with a 1 second delay?

Language- swift
(Still relatively new to programming)

Comment: Can you do a better description of what it is what you want?

Comment: I have an Aarray with words in it, I want those  words to appear in the text field but each word must appear 1 second after each other.

Comment: After a word appear the previous one should disappear or at the end all words will be visible?

Comment: What did you try? Did you check NSTimer's documentation?

Comment: None of the words must disappear. When element #1 is added, element #2 comes after with a delay but everything stats visable. Trying to create something like this   https://www.dropbox.com/s/tq66bn0b2tssn5i/Untitled.mp4?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is you need

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    var array = ["string1", "string2", "string3"]
    var i = 0
    var str: String = ""
    var timer = NSTimer()

    func testFunc() {
        str += "\(array[i])\n"
        textView.text = str
        if i == count(array) - 1 {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
        i += 1
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("testFunc"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: I apologise but I made an error in my wording, im using UITextView, I get an error saying that UITextView does not have a member named 'string Value'

Comment: @Junaid hmm, UITextView have a member "value".

Comment: It runs with no errors, but it then pauses and highlights in green , it tested in in the simulator and on an actual device' class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { '  says Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: @Junaid create new project and add this code to ViewController.swift. It runs without errors and pauses.

Comment: I created a new project and the same thing happens

Comment: @Junaid tell me your email

Answer (score 0):

**Here is Code May It's Help Its Delay 1 Second with DispatchQueue Swift 5**

```
   var new : String = ""
                for a in self.arrayofData{

                    new = new + a + " "
                }


  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {

  self.mytextView.text = self.new

  }
```